Running on Shabbat when it is raining
The Tur in  סימן ש"א writes:

כתיב אם תשיב משבת רגליך ודרשו חז"ל שלא יהא הילוכך של שבת כהילוכך של חול ע"כ אין לו לאדם לרוץ בשבת  כדרך שעושה בחול   אבל אם רץ לדבר מצוה כגון לבהכ"נ או כיוצא בו מותר

Accordingly the Shulchan Aruch paskens :

One should not run on Shabbat unless it is to perform a mitzvah, such as running to the Shul, or something similar.  RAMA: And it is forbidden to walk more than an amah in one step if one can take a smaller step. [Or Zaruah; Hagahos Ashiri]

If someone is walking outdoors (not for mitzvah purposes) and it starts raining, is he/she allowed to run towards cover?

My father was once walking with R’ Chatzkel levenstein zt”l and it started raining. Being a Bachur, he wanted to start running, R’ chatzkel told him he could run but that he himself would walk as it was shabbos and he was machmir but halachicly your allowed

From Halachipedia:
One may run because of the rain, a fear, or another extreme need.
In the footnote (5) he says: "Shemirat Shabbat KeHilchata 29:5, Yalkut Yosef 301:3 cited by Tiferet 301:2. Midrash Rabba (Devarim 18) implies that one shouldn't run on Shabbat even because of the rain. Shevet Halevi 1:58 explains that the reason running is general forbidden unless it is a mitzvah is because someone who is running looks like he is doing something for his personal gain and business as he would do during the week. However, if he's caught in the rain it is permitted to run since it is evident that one is doing so for a specific permitted purpose."
Therefore to answer the question, one may run because of rain.
